# How do I know if the rows of matrix are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given is matrix:

$G'=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&  1&  1&  0&  1&  0& 1& \\ 
 1&  1&  0&  1&  1&  1&  1& 1& \\ 
 0&  1&  0&  1&  1&  0&  0& 1& \\  
 0&  1&  1&  0&  1&  0&  1& 0& \\ 
 0&  0&  1&  0&  1&  1&  1& 0& \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

How do I know if the rows of matrix are linearly independent? How to reduce the matrix so that all rows are linearly independent?

Comment: Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submatrix formed by the first five columns of your matrix has determinant equal to $-2\neq0$. Therefore, the rows of your matrix are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the following statement are equivalent

- rows of matrix are linearly independent
- $rank(G')=5$
- we have no zero rows in the [RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)